# How can I replace an image on a website with a local image in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension, that changes the appereance of the wikipedia page. Now I want to change the image there. I want to replace it with one stored local in my chrome-extension. I want to change some HTML code to display my image. My **manifest.json** looks like this

```
{
    "name" : "name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description" : "some desc",
    "web_accessible_resources" : [
        "images/*.png"
    ],
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "css": ["style.css"],
            "js": ["imgreplace.js"],
            "matches" : ["*://www.wikipedia.de/"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**imgreplace.js**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("wikipedia-logo").innerHTML = this.innerHTML + '<a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/"><img src="chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/wikipedia_logo.png" title="Wikipedia" alt="Wikipedia"/></a>'
```

If I refresh the page nothing happens. No Error.

I've also tried it with the function `injectAdjacentHTML`, but I get the error `injectAdjacentHTML is not a function`.

*How can I replace it?*

Tell me, if you need anything of my code.

Comment: What's in `style.css`?

Comment: @ThomasMueller just a few style changes, inverted colors etc. nothing too important

Comment: You want to replace the Wikipedia logo on all WP pages, not just on https://www.wikipedia.de/, correct? Because https://www.wikipedia.de/ and (for example) https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow_%28Website%29 use different methods to display the WP logo. Therfore, different methods for replacing the logo are required.

Comment: I actually only want to replace it for wikipedia.de .I'm going to make a general version for the actual wiki, which will work on all languages. I don't need it on the en.wikipedia page, because there it doesn't even have a start page. That's why I'm only doing it for the german version for now.

Comment: When I type something into the search bar on https://www.wikipedia.de/ and press enter, it redirects me to https://de.wikipedia.org/ But if you only want to change the logo on the start page, I can write a relatively simple extension that doesn't use innerHTML, which is not a clean method to replace an image.

Comment: You're using Manifest V2, is that intentional? Because the "web_accessible_resources" manifest key has a different format in Manifest V3.

Comment: I have edited the image from Wikipedia. I don't want to do that now for the logo in all other languages as well, so I'll just stay on wikipedia.de for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed some bugs.

imgreplace.js

```js
const path = chrome.runtime.getURL("images/wikipedia_logo.png");

document.getElementsByClassName("wikipedia-logo")[0].innerHTML +=
  '<a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/"><img src="'
  + path + '" title="Wikipedia" alt="Wikipedia"/></a>';
```

Comment: btw if you want to replace it you only need `=` instead of `+=`

Answer (score 0):

This version does essentially the same thing as @NorioYamamoto's version; it's just a little cleaner.

The original WP logo is briefly visible, I don't know how to prevent that. If you use an SVG instead of a PNG, the change happens so quickly that you can barely see the original logo (YMMV).

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name" : "Replace Wikipedia Logo",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "js": ["imgreplace.js"],
            "matches" : ["*://*.wikipedia.de/*"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources" : [
        {
            "resources": ["/images/*.png"],
            "matches": ["*://*.wikipedia.de/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

imgreplace.js

```
try {
    let logo_selector = "#mainbox > div.wikipedia-logo > a > img";
    let logo_imgs = document.querySelectorAll(logo_selector);
    if (logo_imgs.length == 0) {
        throw `The CSS selector "${logo_selector}" didn't find any elements.`;
    }
    else if (logo_imgs.length == 1) {
        logo_imgs[0].src = chrome.runtime.getURL("/images/wikipedia_logo.svg");
    }
    else {
        throw `The CSS selector "${logo_selector}" found more than one element.`;
    }
}
catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```